# Confused with comma's in PHP

Tags: php

I know is a stupid question but well i am trying so hard but i can't figure out on where i am missing the comma i am totally confused ,The below code is giving me an  error.

it would be great if someone can help me out with a referencing on comma and tips / Tricks on them :)

i tried replacing the commas in different places but still it didn't worked out.

```
   <td><?php echo <a href="test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"/>Download! ?></a></td>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing to do with commas (`,`), everything to do with missing quotes (`'` and/or `"`) and with nesting PHP tags

Comment: What would you recommend me to do for this case Sir ?

Comment: why not like that: `<td><a href="test1.php?id=<?=$row['ID']?>">Download</a></td>` ?

Comment: @MarkBaker In some countries I think they call single quotes "inverted commas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be:

```
<td>
    <?php
        echo '<a href="test1.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Download!</a>';
    ?>
</td>
```

Alternatively:

```
<td>
    <a href="test1.php?id=<?=$row['ID']?>">Download!</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for alot +1:D

Comment: Short tags are not always enabled, I suggest you stick to just `<?php echo` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href="test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"/>Download!</a></td>
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to remember is that you do not have to use `echo` to output static HTML content, only for the dynamic part, the variable in you case. The correct version looks like:

```
<td><a href="test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"/>Download!</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate approach typically would be that:

```
<td><a href="test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Download!</a></td>
```

Often it can be shortened, depending on your php configuration:

```
<td><a href="test1.php?id=<?= $row['ID'] ?>">Download!</a></td>
```

To me the second form is more readable, thus my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

There is one redundant `echo` with opening/closing php tags, also you wrongly self-close the `a` tag.

In your html template it is sufficient to write:

```
<td>
    <a href="test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Download!</a>
</td>
```

Code between `<?php` and `?>` is php code which is "injected" in html.

`$row` is array and with `$row['ID']` you get value of specific key from array which is `ID`. You can access the value on this key also with double quotes like `$row["ID"]` there is no difference, because you want to access the key which is referenced by string with value `ID`. You can embrace string with single or double quotes. 
More on strings in php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

When you want to use same quotes in string you have to escape it like

```
<?php 
echo "This is double quote: \"."; //result: This is double quote: ".
?>
```

same with single quote:

```
<?php 
echo 'This is single quote: \'.'; //result: This is single quote: '. 
?>
```

You can echo some other string with value from array for example:

```
<?php echo "this row has id: " . $row["ID"]; ?>
```

so you concatenate string and value with the period/dot.

Or you can access value of variable in string like:

```
<?php
$rowId = 1;
echo "this row has id: $rowId"; //result: this row has id: 1
?>
```

But it is hard to spot it and many IDE's will not highlight it. Better can be to concatenate it with period (`echo "this row has id: " . $rowId;`).

You can also specify value from array, but you have to enclose it with `{}` so the php engine know that it is array variable no the literal

```
<?php echo "this row has id: {$row["ID"]}"; ?>
```

or object property:

```
<?php echo "this row has id: {$row->id}"; ?>
```

But it can also be hard to spot it when you write it like this.

When you want to literally write all this code you can enclose it by single quotes:

```
<?php
echo '<?php echo "this row has id: {$row["ID"]}"; ?>'; //result: <?php echo "this row has id: {$row["ID"]}"; ?>
?>
```

or escape all double quotes and dollar sign `$` and the result will be same:

`<?php
   echo "<?php echo \"this row has id: {\$row[\"ID\"]}\"; ?>";
   ?>`